# Bluetooth GPS to Smart Phone

Tags: gps, android, iphone

Has anyone had any luck intergrating a GPS unit with your Smartphone?  Looking to gain sub 5m accuracy.  Ideally would like the phone to just use the better gps reciever when it is connected.  This goes for any tablets as well.

Also, are there any cheap add-on gps units that get this accuracy for a smart phone?

Anyone done anything like this?

Thad

Comment: Not exactly for smartphones, but there is a device by Nokia which offers +/- 5-10m accuracy and can be connected to wide range of Nokia feature phones. http://europe.nokia.com/find-products/accessories/all-accessories/navigation/gps-modules/ld-4w

Comment: I had not seen that from Nokia.  Good idea, but not any better accuracy than a gps in a smart phone.  I'm just so surprised that trimble hasn't put something out for this.  Seems like it would be a huge market and that the market is moving towards using smartphone/tablets as mobile data collectors

Comment: Beta Tested the Nokia Bluetooth GPS Module LD-4W with a Nokia N97 and N82 - was slow on the cold start 2 mins for a GPS fix - but was quick with assisted GPS and warm start (15 secs). With Sportstracker will store as gpx - can export to kml.

Comment: I'm curious if there's an app that integrates the [SXBlue II](http://www.sxbluegps.com/sxblueII-gps.html) with an iPad.

Comment: wow.  Yeah that would be ideal.  Just shot the company and email to ask price and if they had experience integrating with smartphone/tablet over bluetooth.  I'll post their response.

Comment: $2095.00 #SXBlueII Bluetooth or USB with iPad connection

Comment: Just recieved a quote, same price as above.  Asking for more information about how it overrides current GPS receiver in say, google maps or arcgis app.

Comment: I think you'll also need an antenna, which is built into the Trimble, I think. I wonder what [this antenna](http://www.sxbluegps.com/gis-mapping-accessories.html) costs.

Comment: It's included. Quoted from the rep. "yes, you'll need the antenna; it is part of the system and it will allow you
to use your tablet, no problem.  The price of the SXBlue II GPS, including
all you need to keep it well maintained is $2095.00 plus shipping."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submeter GPS Handheld with **bluetooth** from Trimble

[image]

```
GeoXH or GeoXT 6000 series model to suit your needs:
Product Models  GeoXT   GeoXH
Accuracy    Submeter    Decimeter/Centimeter
Floodlight  Optional    Yes
Cellular modem  Optional    Optional
Camera  5 MP    5 MP

CELLULAR6 & WIRELESS7

    UMTS/HSDPA

    850/900/2100 MHz

    GPRS/EDGE

    850/900/1800/1900 MHz

    Wi-Fi

    802.11 b/g

    Bluetooth

    Version 2.1 + EDR
```

http://www.trimble.com/mappingGIS/geo6.aspx?dtID=technical_specs

Comment: Yes.  But if I were to say open ARCGIS for iphone on my iphone would that GPS be functioning within my app?  Make sense?    I actually have an old geoxt 2005 that has bluetooth but it only allows data transfer not gps integration across the blue tooth connection.

Comment: your option is also 6,000 dollars...  https://store.trimble.com/OA_HTML/ibeCCtpItmDspRte.jsp?section=10420&item=71381   this is another option but again, will it integrate into my apps?  will it override the cellphones built in GPS?

Comment: if you can afford arcgis/iphone then this can be customised to submeter accuracy - http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgis-iphone/api will pull data from your device which you can piggyback the trimble receiver via bluetooth.

Comment: $8195.00 for GeoXH but you get a nice yellow box for $17,995 (you pay for the accuracy)

Comment: ahh.  via the sdk. I had not thought of that before.  We have arcmap, but no server currently. So that would be useless until we went to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't normally answer my own question but this is the best solution so I will.

http://xgps150.dualav.com/

8.5 battery life
2.5m accuracy

The one we mentioned above (#SXBlueII) is 2k because it is survey grade accuracy.  So it has it's place but for most its overkill.

Comment: I doubt you will find this is much better than the internal gps.

Comment: What makes you think that?  Its WAAS compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this depends on which part of the world you are in and what services are available. Coastal areas have marine beacons which facilitate cheap correction. 
Satellite services are available in inland areas which require different hardware and have vastly different pricing.

Answer (score 0):

We provide a number of GPS/GIS data collection and stakeout apps for the iPhone and iPad devices. We have been recommending the Dual XGPS-150A and the Bad Elf GPS receivers to our customers. For those who require better accuracy and have more money to spend, there are the iSXBlue and the EOS Arrow units that one could consider.

Comment: Could you maybe give more specifics.